# Why is group to be set RW in samba share for the client to have access although I set UID and GUI for the client?

Tags: samba

I am running this on Debian Bullseye:

```
pi@RPi64:/mnt/hdd/pibackup $ samba --version
Version 4.13.13-Debian
```

with the share beeing

```
[hgst]
path = /mnt/hdd
public = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
comment = smb share
printable = no
guest ok = no
```

I have some files in the share:

```
pi@RPi64:/mnt/hdd/pibackup $ ll files
total 48
drwxrws--- 5 pi users 4096 Jul  8 18:48 2022-07-08-1848h
```

and mount the share on a client in a VM with

```
/192.168.1.90/hgst      /mnt/hdd        cifs auto,nofail,users,username=,password=,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

I encountered the problem that I was not able to delete files and even not able to enter some directories when I had the files in the share owned by `pi:pi` and the group having no `w` or even no `r`.

They where mounted on the client beeing owned by `ben:ben`.

What I don't understand is: The files can be owned by any **user** on the server and they still will be mounted as writeable because I set the user ID on the client and the file has write permissions set for user. So I would think that since I am seeing the user `ben` on the client and the files have `rw` per user and I am acting as this particular user on the client, I should be allowed to do anything to them.

But I had no permissions to delete files, because the group had just `r` and I did not have permission even to see inside directories that had no rights for group at all.

I was only able to solve the problem by giving the group `rw` on the server. I also changed the ownership to `pi:users`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question up I thought about the rights the user has that I use to log in. `ben` is on the server also in group `users`, like the original owner of the files: `pi`.

So this means that the user I use to log in to the server has limitations according to the original user on the server. `ben` has only `r` on the files, as he is in the same group as `pi`. If the file is even missing the `r` `ben` is not even allowed to see it.

And the group that is set on the client side only has implications for other users on the client. It has nothing to do with group rights on the server. Of course.